# Windows XP installation from USB giving "Cannot find EULA" error

Tags: windows-xp, usb, windows-installation, usb-boot, rufus

I have an old Pavilion zv5200. A few years ago, the hard drive died, and I got rid of it. I also have an external HDD. I want to install Windows XP on it using the original CD for the laptop, and run XP from the HDD until I can get my hands on a 2.5" IDE HDD. Simply putting the disc in and trying to install it to the HDD partition that I set up for it does not work. It BSODs on the loading screen because apparently USB drives are restarted during XP startup, so I heard. Either way, the laptop can definitely boot from USB, so I looked for ways to get it to do so. One way I found was modifying some lines in the files of the installation ISO regarding USB and booting. I put everything back into an ISO and tried to use Rufus to make a bootable flash drive out of it.

Well, the flash drive boots just fine, but after pressing Enter to install XP, it gives an error about not being able to find the EULA. I could not find a solution to this that worked, so I am posting it here. Is the issue because I modified the files, or is there a problem with Rufus? If it is the former, then is it possible at all to get XP to successfully install to and boot from an external HDD? If it is the latter, what should I set so that it will work, if Rufus will work at all for this? I've tried BIOS 0x80, 0x81, and 0x82. The last of those does cause the computer to keep restarting because of some kind of error, which does line up with what was said at one place I checked, but none of the other options seem to work.

Comment: Unless you are trying to install to the exact same computer you won't be able to activate the installation.  Besides that fact, it sounds like the original cd, is defective if it can't find the EULA.

Comment: When I install from the disc it boots just fine, but it's from the flash drive that gives the error, and I'm sure it has something to do with the files I changed, but I can't figure out how to change this. Also, it is to the same computer. Will a non-original HDD work? Possibly different RAM?